# Как увеличить у элемента значение атрибута на 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input class="numb" type="text" data>
    <input class="numb" type="text" data>
    <input class="numb" type="text" data>
    <input class="numb" type="text" data>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#inputs .numb').each(function(){
      // ???
   });
});
```

Что хочу получить:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input class="numb" type="text" data="NumbData1">
    <input class="numb" type="text" data="NumbData2">
    <input class="numb" type="text" data="NumbData3">
    <input class="numb" type="text" data="NumbData4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputs .numb').each(function(ndx){
        $(this).attr('data', 'NumbData' + (ndx+1))
    });
});
```